# Why any class marked final won't allow compiler to devirtualise method call

Tags: java, compiler-construction

In [this article](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2012/02/devirtualizing-method-calls-in-java.html), I was surprised to read:

> I always imagined that having a `final` method meant that the compiler would compile all calls to it using `invokespecial` instead of `invokevirtual`, to "devirtualize" the method calls since it already knows for sure at compile-time where to transfer execution. Doing this at compile time seems like a trivial optimization, while leaving this up to the JIT is far more complex. But no, the compiler doesn't do this. It's not even legal to do it!

Doing this at compile time seems like a trivial optimization, since it already knows for sure at compile-time where to transfer execution.  What's the reason this doesn't happen?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `invokestatic` is for static methods. Final methods are not necessarily static.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. But why invokevirtual compiler should optimise it as its sure that either the method is present of inherited ?

Comment: `invokeSpecial` is something else entirely.  I think that's not a very informative blog.

Comment: The comment by `Anonymous' on December 19 2012 seems to answer this question. Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 3):

Posting [the answer that EJP pointed out in the comments](http://blog.tsunanet.net/2012/02/devirtualizing-method-calls-in-java.html?showComment=1355954272073#c5935368279465475105):

> Java has a separate compilation model, thus it forbids cross-file optimization (with a notable exception, compile-time constant inlining). What if you change the method to non-final, and do not recompile the clients? What if you do runtime bytecode replacement (search for "instrumentation")?
>
> Side note: as an engineer, your expectations should be a function of the tool. This is not C++. Where you can afford an interpreter, bytecode optimization is premature optimization.
>
> Keep your mind object-oriented. You ask the compiler to do it, let it decide the best behind the scenes; if a 20yo compiler does not do it, it's probably unimportant. -O is well documented (at least on Oracle's JDK) and it just inlines the private and static methods inside the file that declares them.